# How to unescape a sequence include \u and \U?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some strings in a `.resx` file include some sequences like this:

```
\u26A0 warning
```

So i use the following code to unscape it

```
str = Regex.Unescape(str);
```

Now, when i see the result everything works well (with **`\u`**) and it show the related **emoji**.

*But* `Regex.Unescape(...)` method dose not work when the input string is include **`\U`** like this:

```
\U0001F4D8 book
```

and it return this error:

> **Error:**  Unrecognized escape sequence **\U**

My question:

- Is there another method in .Net framework to Unescape the sequences include **\u** and **\U**?
- If there is not an embed method, how can i write a helper method manually to do it?

---

Edit:

When i read string from the resx file it has double backslash, i should convert these Unicode sequences to their characters:

[image]

Comment: Why are you un-escaping the contents of the resx file, it's just text and \U is just for unicode escape.

Comment: @GlennCuevas, when i apply Regex.Unescape on the resource text and send it to the target social network. It show the emoji well else i see the code (\u26A0) instead of the related emoji.

Comment: How about using str.Replace(@"\U", @"\u")

Comment: @GlennCuevas, \u with 8 digit is incorrect in C#. \u should has 4 digit and \U should has 8 digit.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, according to source code of [`Regex.Unescape`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/Regex.cs,757110696dd94ec7),  [`RegexParser.ScanCharEscape`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexParser.cs,9247c4f54f140280), `\U` is not handled.

Instead, you could consider a manual conversion with help of [`char.ConnvertFromUtf32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string converted = char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse("0001F4D8", NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

This is a draft implementation. (The annoying complexity comes from an attempt to distinguish `\U` and `\\U`.)

```
static string Unescape(string str)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int startIndex = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        int index = IndexOfBackslashU(str, startIndex);
        if (index == -1)
            return builder.Append(Regex.Unescape(str.Substring(startIndex))).ToString();
        builder.Append(Regex.Unescape(str.Substring(startIndex, index - startIndex)));
        string number = str.Substring(index + 2, 8);
        builder.Append(char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(number, NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
        startIndex = index + 10;
    }
}

static int IndexOfBackslashU(string str, int startIndex)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int index = str.IndexOf(@"\U", startIndex);
        if (index == -1)
            return index;
        bool evenNumberOfPreviousBackslashes = true;
        for (int k = index-1; k >= 0 && str[k] == '\\'; k--)
            evenNumberOfPreviousBackslashes = !evenNumberOfPreviousBackslashes;
        if (evenNumberOfPreviousBackslashes)
            return index;
        startIndex = index + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not write `\U26A0` in my question! I wrote `\u26A0` and i mentioned it works well by `\u`. My problem is Unescaping a text include `\U`.

Comment: @RAM Sorry, I misread it the first  time. `char.ConvertFromUtf32` could be an option, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Thank you, during your previous and new answer i searched and tried to write a method and finally solved it. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032496/how-to-unescape-a-sequence-include-u-and-u/40033786#40033786) is like your answer but include a full method to solve the problem. I did not know any better way too.

Comment: When i read the `str` from the resource file, its backslash escaped and there is 2 backslash. Just like first line in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhNY3.jpg). So when i use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032496/how-to-unescape-a-sequence-include-u-and-u/40033786#40033786) it works well.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this method and the problem solved:

```
public static string UnescapeIt(string str)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\\)(?:\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8})", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return regex.Replace(str,
        m =>
        {
            if (m.Value.IndexOf("\\U", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
                return char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse(m.Value.Replace("\\U", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            return Regex.Unescape(m.Value);
        });
}
```

It *unescape* `\u` sequences and *convert* `\U` sequences to related character. So we can see the emojis.

**Use:**

```
str= UnescapeIt(str);
```

**Result:**
[image]

---

**Update:**
I changed the regex from

```
\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}
```

to

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8})
```

Now it will fail the match if we have a backslash before `\u` or `\U`

Comment: It seems that it (1) does not cover the case of real leading backslash, e.g.. `\\U` and (2) does not unescape anything except `\u` and `\U`. (But maybe such cases are not possible in your scenario.)

Comment: @AlexD if you want see the `str` value before apply `UnescapeIt` method please look at the `str` value in the **image inside my question** (first line in the watch panel, there). Now when i use `UnescapeIt`, the result is inside the **image in this answer** (first line in the watch panel, here). I'm working with it, it works well. Thank you again ;)

Comment: Try `string s = @"c:\\temp\\u0021.jpg";` `UnescapeIt` returns `"c:\\\\temp\\!.jpg"`, but `Regex.Unescape` returns `"c:\\temp\\u0021.jpg"`.

Comment: @AlexD, your mentioned point was correct. So i changed my answer to cover it. What do you think about my answer now?

Comment: if `\U` is not used, then `UnescapeIt` and  `Regex.Unescape` should give the same result. Try `string s = @"\\\u26A0"; if (Regex.Unescape(s) != UnescapeIt(s)) Console.WriteLine("NOK, {0}", s);`